# Opening view controller from web view

Tags: html, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I want to have a web view that loads a webpage. Webpage has few buttons and when you click a button from the web page it has to open a view-controller. 
Is this possible?

Comment: refer this https://benoitpasquier.fr/ios-and-javascript/

Comment: @RohitKP is that swift?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I bet you are gonna use UKWebView and yes its possible to communicate between your webview and website through evaluateJavaScript(). In this way one can easily communicate between their website and app:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('someElement').innerText") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: And that is for swift?

Comment: I need the function when you click a button can it detect when a specific JavaScript function is ran and I can put onclick in the the button